# Disable absolute position of items in isotope

Tags: html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm working on portfolio and I need to implement my way for positioning portfolio items, isotope library always use absolute position with left and top properties for position portfolio elements, I tried to overwrite absolute position but how to get rid of left and top properties
I use the following CSS rule for portfolio item

```
.portfolio-item{
     position: relative !important;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     float: left;
}
```

but elements still has left and top attributes as following samples of portfolio elemets after isotope library loaded

```
<article class="portfolio-item pf-audio" style="position: absolute; left: 212px; top: 0px;"></article>
<article class="portfolio-item pf-websites" style="position: absolute; left: 424px; top: 0px;"></article>
```

How can I use my own way to position elements

Comment: have you tried `inherit` or `initial` ?

Comment: I have tried initial and it works also it works with position:static !important;

Comment: I'll add my answer then, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

`left: initial`

and

`top: initial`